# My web app calls a console app for a function. The console app shall send the results via named pipe. Which app should be the server in this case?

Tags: c#, named-pipes

I have a ASP Net Core based web app (App-1) that will call a second C# console app (App-2) for a specific function (with Process.Start). When App-2 is executed, it shall connect to a remote OPC server and read some data from it. The values shall be sent over "named pipes" to App-1. Afterwards App-2 shall terminate itself.

In general I have understood how the named pipe machanism works. The named pipe-server is waiting for a connection from a client that requires data from the server.

What is unclear for me:
Which side should be the client and which side the server in my case?

If my web app (App-1) is the named pipe-server, that would mean that my console app (App-2) will connect to the named pipe-server (as client) as soon as it has read data from the rOPC server.  But in my case it will not request any data from the web app (App-1). It will send some data to it. Is that possible?

With other words: Can the named pipe client connect to a named pipe server for just sending data to it? (Instead of requesting data)

Comment: What is a "remote OPC server"?

Comment: why can't the ASP.NET Core web-application call `Process.Start` itself?

Comment: @Dai App-2 is used for reading data from remote CNC machines that have OPC DA servers. Perhaps this detail is not neccesary. I have written this just to explain that App-2 has to fulfill a special task, that app-1 cannot do itself.
app-1 (ASP.NET Core weab app) is calling App-2 with Process.Start. I mean app-1 is directly calling app-2.